# Solving an equation in a specfic region

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, regions, trigonometry, frequency

Good morning,

I want to find a solution to the following equation:

$$\left|u\cdot\sin\left(2\pi\cdot f\cdot t\right)\right|=u\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{a}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space t=\dots\tag1$$

The sine-function is a periodic function, so I want only one solution and that is the solution that is between the follwing boundaries:

$$\frac{1}{2\cdot f}<t<\frac{3}{4\cdot f}\tag2$$

Now, alle the variables are real numbers and bigger than zero.

> Question: How can Mathematica 10.0 solve this question? Or approximate the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With new variables/parameters `ft=f t, fa=f a`, assuming `u>0`, you have to solve the equation  `-Sin[2 Pi ft] == Exp[ -ft/fa] ,1/2 < ft < 3/4`.

```
sol[fa_?NumericQ] :=NMinimize[{1, {-Sin[2 Pi ft] == Exp[ -ft/fa], 1/2 < ft <3/4}},ft  ][[2]]     

sol[.5] (*{ft -> 0.553605} *)
Plot[ ft /. sol[fa] , {fa, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic},AxesLabel -> {f a, f t}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I need to find a general code where I know $\text{f}$ and $\text{a}$ and I need to solve for $t$. I don't need to know how to plot

Comment: `sol[]`is the numerical function you asked for! The adaption on your parameters f, a, t is easily done ...

Comment: sol[] is not a function in Mathematica 10.0. And why do you use $-\sin$? And $\text{f}$ and $t$ are two different things so writing $ft$ is a bit confusing. The only unknown in the equation is $t$

Comment: sol[] is a user defined function I gave you in my code! In the given range of f *t you can substitude Abs[Sin[...]] by -Sin[].  Resubstituting `ft by f*t, fa by f* a` seems to be easily solvable...